# How to get Jenkins to use a proxy when updating plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am running a setup where Jenkins is running behind ngnix, but jenkins needs to use a bluecoat proxy to update plugins.

I have tried updating the advanced proxy settings page but it is not working and have verified that I can wget http://mirror.xmission.com/jenkins/updates/current/update-center.json when I have the http_proxy and https_proxy system variables.

I have also tried updating /etc/profile as I see that /etc/init.d/jenkins that they use su jenkins -l when starting Java

Thanks,
Walt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

The way that I solved it was to edit /etc/default/jenkins and update JAVA_ARGS to use my proxy

JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=foo.proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=foo.proxy.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=80"

cheers,
Stephen